# How to delete duplicate rows with one condition that the other column is null in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table looks like below

```
Lead_id         Email               Touchpoint_Date
null          | e@gmail.com        | August 16, 2014 8:58:11 PM 
111           | e@gmail.com        | August 16, 2014 8:58:11 PM
222           | e@gmail.com        | August 5,  2014 4:12:07 AM
null          | f@gmail.com        | August 18, 2014 9:58:11 AM 
111           | f@gmail.com        | August 18, 2014 9:58:11 AM
```

And I would like to delete all the rows that have same date (like row 1 and row 2, row 4 and row 5) and remain the row with lead_id not null. How should I do that in Mysql?

Comment: There are lots of other questions about removing duplicates, and some of them should include using criteria to decide which to keep. Please do some research and post your attempted code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to delete the duplicates dates

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX(date);
```

This query will delete the duplicates values in your table and after you can drop drop it if you want

Comment: "and remain the row with lead_id not null"

Comment: Thanks. If I create this unique index first, would this drop with row that lead_id is not null?

Comment: I don't know if you want to keep some rows with `null` id, but you can drop all the rows with null ids before adding this index : `DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table_name
    WHERE id=null
)`

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Or have you found something on your side?